# How to set iOS launch images for two different starting screens

Tags: ios, image, launch

In iOS apps you should set a launch image that looks similar to your first screen. Apple advises against using splash screens as launch images, but what if your app has a completely different first screen the first time it is launched (say registration screen) than the usual first screen? Is there a way to set two launch images and if not is there a way around it other than a blank or splash screen?